# Glassfish 5.1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application validation fails for EJB

Tags: glassfish, ejb, war, jndi, glassfish-5

Glassfish 5.1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application validation fails.

EJB

```
@Stateless
public class DataAccessorBean {
    

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        
    }
    
}
```

JSF backing Bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    DataAccessorBean dataAccessorBean;

}
```

Deployment error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application validation fails for given application [my-web] for jndi-name []
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:89)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:617)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:211)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:73)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:857)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:797)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
```

If removing EJB bean from the web app, deployment will be successful.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your JNDI-Datasource. Do you have a persistence.xml?